# Get Record Data for Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, record, lightning-web-components

I have been following [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_example) to create a Web Component that gets a records information, however I am having trouble getting this to work with custom object... Is there extra steps you need to take to get this to work with custom objects?

For example, here is what I have in my own code:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const STUDENT_FIELDS = [
    'Student__c.Name',
    'Student__c.username__c'
]

export default class StudentCourseRelationship extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    // STUDENT
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', STUDENT_FIELDS}) student;

    get studentName() {
        // OPTION 1
        return getFieldValue(this.student.data, STUDENT_FIELDS[0]);
        // OPTION 2
        return this.student.data.fields.Name.value
    }

    get studentUsername() {
        // OPTION 1
        return getFieldValue(this.student.data, STUDENT_FIELDS[1]);
        // OPTION 2
        return this.student.data.fields.username__c.value
    }

}
```

As you can see, in my `get` methods I have explained 2 options. In `Option 1`, nothing errors but nothing is displayed in the view where I attempt to display `studentName` and `studentUsername`. And in `Option 2`, I get the error:  `[undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.student.data.fields')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed to specify the `fields` attribute in `@wire` declaration. The `@wire` decorator should be declared as below (note `fields: STUDENT_FIELDS`):

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: STUDENT_FIELDS}) student;
```

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_example):

> The `@wire` decorator tells `getRecord` to get the values of the specified **fields** on the record with the specified  `$recordId`.

The `fields` attribute being used in the JS functions contains the response from the [`Record`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record.htm) data (excerpt below). And that, in your current declaration, you haven't mapped this attribute to the fields that you are retrieving.

> The field data for this record, matching the requested layout and mode.

Comment: Even after adding the `fields` declaration, I still get the error `[undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.student.data.fields')]`

Comment: Try refreshing your component, it could be a caching issue.

Comment: Returning `getFieldValue(this.student.data, STUDENT_FIELDS[0]);` works fine.